# find the intersection of sets

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

We are given n sets of integers of different sizes. Each set can contain duplicates also. I have to find the intersection of sets. If an element is present multiple times in all the sets, it should be added to the result.

For example, consider there are three sets {0,5,5,3,4} {5,2,3,5,6} {1,3,5,5,6}. The intersection of the given sets should be {3,5,5}

My approach is :

1.Sort the arrays.

2.Compare every element starting from the smallest array and update the count.

Is there a more efficient approach to find the intersection?

Comment: That seems pretty close to optimal.

Comment: Mathematically, sets don't contain duplicates; multisets or bags can contain duplicates.

Comment: With multi-cores, perhaps a parallel insertion sort (of course your data must be sufficiently large for this to be worth it).

Comment: {0,5,5,3,4}, {1,3,5,5,6}, and {3,5,5} aren't sets. If you're *really* dealing with sets, the most efficient implementation would be to use bit arrays.

Comment: "Is there a more efficient approach to find the intersection?" -- Yes indeed; see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "sets" contain only small integers, then they can be represented by an array of counts ... e.g., {5,2,3,5,6} is

```
index 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
count 0 0 1 1 0 2 1
```

The intersection of such sets is the min of the counts:

```
      index 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
            -------------
{0,5,5,3,4} 1 0 0 1 1 2 0
{5,2,3,5,6} 0 0 1 1 0 2 1
{1,3,5,5,6} 0 1 0 1 0 2 1  
min         0 0 0 1 0 2 0 = {3,5,5}
```

If the values aren't small integers but there are few of them, just keep an array of the values -- that serves as a map between the values and the small integers, which are the indices of the array.

If there are so many values that having an array of counts for each set is too expensive, use a map from values to counts to represent each "set", together with the array of the values ... then iterate over the array to produce each value, iterating over the maps to get the counts and calculating their min. For this you would need a hash table or binary tree library to implement the maps ... or use any of the numerous more modern languages than C that provide such collection types as a matter of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, create a dictionary  for each of the arrays, traverse each one adding to their counters, and adding to a "global" dictionary of  if a new number is detected. Then, you select from "global" dictionary the next number (it's guaranteed to exist at least in ONE of the counter dictionaries) and then you get minimum of all the counters. Of course, if you encounter a null in a single dictionary, this number is not added to the result. Otherwise, add "minimum found" amount of "number" to the result array. With such dictionary structures, the complete complexity of the algorithm is about `O(n*m)` where M is maximum of your sets' sizes, and N is their quantity, while if you sort your sets, the complexity is `O(n*m*log(m))` which is considerably bigger if your sets consist of more than 1000 elements each.

Comment: I think it's not right to multiply number of the sets by the maximum set capacity, as you'll eventually add more than what is there, I'd say O(n) where n: number of elements in all sets

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer We have to query each and every element in those sets in order to correctly form the result, and they are at most `n*m`, so we can't get O() function of less than this. M is not "set capacity", it's the maximum of what's given at the start of algorithm. A set capaciy can be as large as 2^32, with the sets themselves being of size 5 as in the example.

Comment: Using m both for bag size and number-of-distinct-keys in map-of-counts is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, **compile in C99** (*don't forget to implement get,insert,remove functions first*):

```
struct MyNode { MyNode * next; int value; int frequency; }

// returns MyNode pointer when value exist
MyNode * get(MyNode * head, int val);

// insert a new value, with frequency = 1
void insert(MyNode * head, int val);

// remove an element from the linked-list
bool remove(MyNode * head, int val);

int * intersection (int ** set, int w, int * h)
{
    MyNode * head = 0;
    MyNode * temp = 0;
    int finalSize = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<w; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<h[i]; j++)
        {
            temp = get(head, set[i][j]);

            if (temp == 0)
            {
                insert(head, set[i][j]);
                finalSize++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->frequency++;
            }
        }
    }

    temp = head;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        if (temp->frequency != w)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            remove(head, temp->value);
            finalSize--;
        }
        else
            temp = temp->next;
    }

    int * intersection = (int*)malloc(finalSize*sizeof(int));

    temp = head;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        intersection[k++] = temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return intersection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only optimization I would suggest to your solution would be to convert your arrays (they are not really sets because they have duplicates) to key-value dictionaries so that the key would be the element of an array and the value would be the number of occurrences. For your test example: {0,5,5,3,4} {5,2,3,5,6} {1,3,5,5,6} the dictionaries would look like that

```
{0 => 1, 3 => 1, 4 => 1, 5 => 2}
{2 => 1, 3 => 1, 5 => 2, 6 => 1}
{1 => 1, 3 => 1, 5 => 2, 6 => 1}
```

Then you compare pairs of dictionaries starting from the smallest dictionary and if the element occurs in both - you take the smaller number of occurrences.
This optimization will save time required to deal with duplicates.

The resulting dictionary would be: {3 => 1, 5 => 2} - you could convert it back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already covered the idea of representing each "set" (or, more formally, "bag") by [arrays of counts, or maps of counts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676923/15472). This is especially useful if there is a lot of duplication going on, and if there are not that many keys per bag. Given N bags with M elements each, K of which are distinct, the complexity for both translating into array/map representation and generating the result would be `O(N x M) + O(N x K)`. Notice that repeatedly looking for intersections of B bags only costs `O(B x K)`, since you can reuse the map representations.

You can also gain a lot of efficiency if you *order* the pairwise intersections correctly. For example, if one of the bags only contains a single element, there are only two possible answers: either all the other bags also contain that element (and the result is that element by itself), or at least one of them does not. This would allow you to totally ignore the rest of the contents of other sets. In this extreme case, run-time of the actual intersection would drop to `O(N)`, a K-fold improvement.

In general, **if bags have wildly differing numbers of unique elements, sorting their maps by increasing size (number of unique elements)** adds a cost of `O(N log N)`, but allows you to skip a lot of keys while calculating intersections, **reducing intersection time to `O(N x K_min)`**, where `K_min` is the size of the smallest unique-element count.

Something similar is done during database query optimization to greatly improve query time.